# Count number of azure function instances based on application logs

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I'm running a azure function in the consumption plan with .NET 6 and in-process model with service bus triggered target based scaling with Maximum Scale Out Limit set to 16 for the function app.

Running it with a test workload and the scale controller logs show that the number of instances did not exceed 16 though it went up and down multiple times so over the time of the test execution it ran on more than 16 unique instances.

Now I'm trying to get the number of instances from the App Instights logs with this query:

```
traces | where operation_Name == "MyFunctionsName" 
and customDimensions.prop__MyCustomTestRunId == "12345"
and timestamp > datetime('2024-2-13 15:26:00.0') and timestamp < datetime('2024-2-13 15:26:10.0') 
| distinct cloud_RoleInstance
```

And I'm getting 29 instances. It did scale up and down to give more than 16 instaces total, but not over this short 10 second period (and even considering all scale ups that's still less that 29 instances).

Or when I graph it with the following query it's showing that it grew up to 29 and never decreased, which is strange considering that it scaled up and down several times

```
traces | where operation_Name == "MyFunctionsName" 
and customDimensions.prop__MyCustomTestRunId == "12345"
| summarize ['active instances'] = count_distinct(cloud_RoleInstance) by bin(timestamp, 10sec)
| render timechart
```

[image: cloud_RoleInstance instances over time]

What am I missing here?
Is cloud_RoleInstance the wrong column to use for counting instances? Are the queries wrong?

Comment: looking around, I found this answer that might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/64980278/4317508

Comment: @ViniciusDeschamps, thanks, but unfortunately this is the same as my query in the question (count_distict = dcount) so it gives the the same results

Comment: Can you share the output which you are getting using the first query? I believe using cloud_RoleInstance you can get the distinct instances or else have you tried using operation_Id instead?